# Catch-22 UNIX Shell Zsh

Tags: macos, shell, unix, zsh

I was fooling around with .zshrc files, and now I am locked out of my terminal with "No such shell function 'accept-line'".

It would be easy to just go and undo the change in the .zshrc file, but my terminal autoloads into zsh, so there is no way to edit the dotfile.

I have looked all around for a way to edit hidden files in El Capitan, but to no avail.

Comment: Just use any decent text editor, e.g. [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) - click on "Show Hidden Items" in the open file dialog to see files such as `.zshrc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your mention of 'El Capitan' I infer that you might be on OS X and using Terminal.app? If so, please add a tag for that, or state that clearly.

If so, you could duplicate a Terminal profile in the preferences and under Settings->Shell / Startup set e.g. `/bin/bash` as the command and untick "run inside shell". That should give you a bash which will ignore `.zshrc`.

Otherwise, look for similar settings in your terminal emulator. Most should have such a setting somewhere.